# Changing the Partition Names of a Ubuntu Live USB Made with Mkusb

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, live-usb

I've created a Live USB of Ubuntu 18.04.2, and used mkusb to do so that I would have more than 4GB of persistent storage. The process I followed is the same as  [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/).

I'd like to rename the partition names (currently casper-rw for the Live install and usbdata for the 'shared' partition) but am uncertain if this will cause any problems or break the system.

I will admit to not being well versed in Linux so I do apologise if I missed out any important information or something obvious on other questions which would answer this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is my experience that a persistent partition must be named **casper-rw**, (similar to /), or **home-rw**, (similar to /home). Home directory data is kept in casper-rw if there is no home-rw file or partition. It is easy to add an ext4 home-rw partition to a mkusb install. The **usbdata** partition may be named whatever you like.

Comment: @user68186 That's not a comment!  Than's an answer...  Now you're getting upvoted on the comment instead of your answer, so post one, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote!

Comment: @Fabby I was not sure.

Comment: @user68186 You are now!  **:-)** Post!

Comment: @Fabby Done! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The persistent partition is `casper-rw`

According to [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence#Creating_the_.22casper-rw.22_File_System), "the only special consideration (for the persistent partition) is that we must give the formatted partition the label `casper-rw`”. So, you should not rename this partition to something else. If you do, the *persistent* part of the Live USB installation won't be able to find it, and it will not be able to persistently save any changes you make to the system.

## The shared data partition `usbdata`

There are no requirements for the name of this partition. You can rename it using `Gparted` while booted from either an internal drive installation of Ubuntu or a different Live USB installation of Ubuntu. This "other" Live USB need not be persistent. It is better to boot from a different installation of Ubuntu so that the `usbdata` partition is not mounted or in use while you try to change its name.

Hope this helps

Comment: As promised!  **:-) ;-)**

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated getting confirmation on both points.